# How does SetConnMaxLifetime works on golang database/sql

Tags: sql, database, go

I am confused by the [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.SetConnMaxLifetime) of the `func (db *DB) SetConnMaxLifetime(d time.Duration)` that states:

> SetConnMaxLifetime sets the maximum amount of time a connection may be
>   reused.
>
> Expired connections may be closed lazily before reuse.

Does this mean that **idle** connections are closed after `d` has expired or that connections are closed in any case (either idle or not) after `d` has expired like `SetConnMaxLifetime` suggests?
Also what does closing lazily mean in this case and is it possible to implement a timeout using this method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, `sql.DB` will not close an active connection. The cleaner only runs over the free connection pool.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. what does `be closed lazily` mean?

Comment: @fitti: it means it can be closed at any time, not necessarily synchronously with returning the connection to the pool.